# Git format patch to not display in Jenkins console

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins, patch

I am using `git format patch [commit_id]` in Jenkins job which generates number of patches as shown below:

```
git format patch 198h2idn3912
```

This generates say 4 patches

```
0001-Test1.patch<br>
0002-Test2.patch<br>
0003-Test3.patch<br>
0004-Test4.patch`<br>
```

The above is displayed in Jenkins console.

My requirement is to generate same patches but it should not display in console as if there are 1000s or more number of patches then console grows big and becomes difficult to open.

Comment: One way I found is to redirect the output to a file. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have the [option `--quiet`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt--q):

```
-q
--quiet
```

> Do not print the names of the generated files to standard output.

That way, no need for output redirection.